# Adding string values from previous row to next row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that every once in a while separates the text from the first cell in a row into two rows and fills the column values as None and NaN in the first row and then fills the actual column values into the second row.

Here is an example:

```
df

   House_Type       Area          Shape

   Blue House       3456          circle
   Red house        2345          square
   Small Green      NaN           None
   House            987           square
```

On these occasions I want to add the string from the first cell in house type of the split row (Small Green) to the the first cell of house type in the second part of the split row (House). Example below for reference.

The end result looking something like this:

```
  df

   House_Type             Area        Shape

   Blue House             3456          circle
   Red house              2345          square
   Small Green            NaN           None
   Small Green House      987           square
```

I wrote a function to do this but it just comes back looking like the original dataframe. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Code:

```
def row_clean(df):
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        if df.Shape.values[i] == None:
            df.House_Type.values[i + 1] = df.House_Type.values[i] + ' ' + df.House_Type.values[i + 1]

    return df
```

Comment: if df.Shape.values[i] is None:

Comment: @Alam that still returns the same original df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def row_clean(df):
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df.Shape.values[i]):
        df.House_Type.values[i + 1] = df.House_Type.values[i] + ' ' + df.House_Type.values[i + 1]

return df
```

Comment: This is closer but the house type looks like [  Blue House Small Green, Red House...] now.

Comment: My mistake, I left out an [i] so this works perfectly!